# matlab changes to fminbnd

Tags: matlab

I have a program using fminbnd and it works perfectly on my new version of MATLAB.  Some of my colleagues have an older version 2010b and it yields and error message.  Have there been any major changes to this function over the past two years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use the `LargeScale` algorithm ? (default case).
It was improved in 2011b:

> Enhanced Robustness in Nonlinear Solvers
>
> More solvers now attempt to recover from errors in the evaluation of
> objective functions and nonlinear constraint functions during
> iteration steps, or, for some algorithms, during gradient estimation.
> The errors include results that are NaN or Inf for all solvers, or
> complex for fmincon and fminunc. If there is such an error, the
> algorithms attempt to take different steps. The following solvers are enhanced:
>
> [...]
>
> fminunc LargeScale algorithm
>
> [...]

See [release notes](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/toolbox/optim/rn/bsqj_zi.html#bsrhtz8-1)